# Does there exist a closed, regular, non-self-intersecting developable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have had only minimal exposure to differential geometry in my education thus far. I am currently searching for a surface that has the following properties:

1. Surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$
2. Zero Gaussian curvature (aka [developable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface))
3. No self intersections
4. Closed
5. Regular (or at least $C^2$? I'm a little confused about how to phrase this constraint, but I don't want an infinitely "scrunched" surface like a [flat torus](https://www.pnas.org/content/109/19/7218#sec-9) or a surface with a cusp or vertex, like a [sphericon.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericon)

I haven't been able to find a surface that satisfies these qualities online, nor do I have the expertise to prove or disprove its existence, nor create it if it does exist. Any further reading on the subject would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any (real analytic) developable surface must be (a subset of) a plane, a cylinder, a cone, or a tangent developable (the surface of tangent lines to a smooth curve in space — this surface will have a cuspidal edge along the curve). If by closed you mean a compact surface without boundary, there is none. Every developable surface must be ruled, and ruled surfaces are never compact.

See page 61 and Exercise 12 on page 42 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: Your answer is clear and concise. Furthermore, your textbook will be great further reading on the subject. I've already saved it! Thanks so much.

Comment: Get back to me with further questions if you want to, @trytryagain.